# How to give ftp access to sub-directory only not to parent

Tags: linux, apache

I want to give SFTP access to user `tom` for directory `/var/www/html/my_project/`. while I don't want to give any SFTP access to directory `/var/www/html/`.

currently `/var/www/html/my_project/` and `/var/www/html/` is owned by apache user.I need to give access only to  `/var/www/html/my_project/` directory for both user tom as well as apache.

Once access is given tom can access all the directories which are under /var/www/html/my_project/.

Please help me I am struggling since a long time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: `man mount` then `/--bind`

Comment: @Leigh it will be great if you can explain more

Comment: type `man mount`, then type `/--bind`

Answer (score 1):

Try to jail the user to a particular directory.

See this link for steps [Jail a user on Ubuntu or Debian](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu)

SFTP works on SSH encryption, hence it is more secure over FTP.